# Chromium doesn't show orange highlights

Tags: chromium

Even when I trying changing the themes and icons, it doesn't change the corresponding icon color. All that's there is a faintly dull grey highlight.

Comment: Have you tried in settings 'Use GTK theme?' (the theme won't be applied to web content like buttons though, but it should change the icons uses and the window border and menus). Please can you add a screenshot (if you can't due to privileges stuff use http://imgur.com ), as it would help as this is a issue with themes/styling..

Answer (score 0):

Simply, if inaccurately, the Chromium and Google Chrome browsers now use something called "Aura" and so many GTK+ aspects no longer apply.

You can read about Aura here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura-desktop-window-manager and note the section titled "Platform Native Control (aka Gtk/HWND) Elimination".

I don't know to what extent your difficulties are related to the use of Aura.